# Using C# how to convert RGB to YCrCb and YCrCb to RGB

Tags: c#

Using C# I need to convert RGB value to YCrCb format and also YCrCb to RGB. please anyone suggest a way.

Comment: Yes, the usual way. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into this (Complete source code): [AForge Image Processing Library](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidC25253D9257225B8F879EAF0A9F1161C6FABE14B.aspx)

They have provided you the complete class to do this:

You can easily locate functions like this **RGB2YCbCr**